# Read the historical values of a variable at the last bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I read the past values of a series variable at the last bar? For example, in my script below I would like the `last_bar_n` variable to contain all the historical values of the `n` variable, not just the last one.

How can I do that, please? Maybe a function is more appropriate here?

I need this in a script where at the last bar I have a variable (such as `last_bar_n`, in my example here) that will change its content in a `for` loop. With each loop, this variable should read the historical values of other global variables (such as `n` here).

Thank you!

Alex

```
//@version=5
indicator("")

var float last_bar_n = na

n = close

if (barstate.islast)

    last_bar_n := n
    
    // this does not show the previous bar value, so there are no historical values in this variable
    label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(last_bar_n[1]), textcolor=#ffffff)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pinescript, all variables are series

```
if barstate.islast

   for i = 1 to n
       label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(last_bar_n[i]), textcolor=#ffffff)
```

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for a solution (if there is one) that works using the approach I wrote above.